# Send programmatically notification with FCM

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I hope you're well, I need some orientation since I'm new to using the Cloud Messaging service of the Firebase suite.

Here I have 2 applications, ***myapp_client*** and ***myapp_admin***. What happens is the following, with ***myapp_admin*** I publish information that I insert in the ***Firestore database*** and with ***myapp_client*** I read this information inserted in the ***Firestore database.***

What I want is that once the ***myapp_admin*** application publishes this information then it sends a notification to the users of the ***myapp_client*** application who can then open it.

I've done some research and I haven't found a good documentation (even the official one) that would explain how to send notifications programmatically from the dart/flutter code without using ***Cloud functions*** (This is possible)?

Can you please guide me? I'm not asking you to give me solutions but to guide me to find the solutions I need to implement such an operation.

THANKS

Comment: FCM does not support sending messages securely from mobile apps.  It requires the use of a backend, so that your service account credentials are not available to the world (which would be a huge security problem).

Comment: Can i use Cloud messaging API to achieve that?

Comment: You would still need to put your backend credentials into your app, which is the security problem that you need to avoid.  It's better to use a backend.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing will certainly require you to listen for new snapshots from a collection of notifications in Firestore in a background process of **myapp_client**, and then trigger a local notification when new data is received by using a plugin like [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). Here is a helpful [article](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124) explaining how code execution in the background can be done in Flutter.

If you want the **myapp_client** app to receive the data published by **myapp_admin** as push notifications even when your app is in the background without executing code in the background, the only viable and tested solution that works really well with Flutter AFAIK, is using Cloud functions.

Comment: I will read the article you proposed and see if it can solve my problem, thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The description by Nikolai using the local notification package together with client subscriptions is a fine solution.

Out of curiosity, why do you want to avoid cloud functions?
Using CF is a quite straightforward way to do it.

1. admin write information to firestore
2. cloud function triggers with the onWrite function on collection/doc that match where your admin wrote the data.
3. cloud function use FCM to send push notification to a topic that your clients subscribe to, or to individual devices.

Comment: I need to change my payment formula to be able to use cloud function, I plan to do it later but for now for test purposes, it's not really obvious. But I'm obviously planning to change my payment plan to be able to use all the services that Firebase offers.

Comment: Okey. FYI, I think that the solution by Nikolai will generate an increased cost and more strain on firestore, and more data to be passed to/from each client over the network. Each client will have to subscribe to the given snapshots which will count as reads for each one. Instead, your CF would only trigger once for the added data and then just send the notification to "all" applicable clients.